# Chrome and IE not showing ajax loaderr gif

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, google-chrome, loader

Ok i have a function that executes 14 ajax calls. Before the loop i show the loader div, when loop ends i hide the loader loop. This works only in FF and not in IE and Chrome. Why is that? I tried two different approaches and still i get no results.

Approach 1:

```
function myFunction(x,y,z)
{       
    $(".loader").show();

    for( 1 to 14 loop ) 
    {   
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'some.php',
            data: 'my data string here',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'html',
            //timeout: 30000,
            success: function(data)
            {
             // do some stuff (show/hide divs, increase some counters, some maths, etc) 
            }
        }); 

    }

    $(".loader").hide();

}
```

Approach 2

```
Same as approach 1, but:
- remove show/hide loader div from function
- add to my document ready the following code:

    $(".loader")
      .hide()
      .ajaxStart(function() { $(this).show(); })
      .ajaxStop(function() { $(this).hide(); });
```

Both approaches work in Firefox but not one of them works in IE and Chrome. Why? How can i make this to work cross-browser? Thank you for any advice.

**Edit:**

- no errors in console (firefox or chrome)
- if i turn asynch to true, i see no loader in no browser, although i see the ajax calls being executed in console

After request, here is the actual code:

```
function nearBydates(depdate, depPort, arrPort, triptype, direction, route, count)
{

    var datesArray = new Array();
    var date = new Date();
    var parts = depdate.split('-');

    $(".loader").show();
    var oddEven = 'row1';

    // find dates -1 week
    var earlierCounter = 0;
    for(var i=14; i>=1; i--) 
    {
        var d = Date.parse(depdate);
        var nextDay = d.add(-i).day();
        var stringDate = nextDay.toString("yyyy-MM-dd");

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'page.php',
            data: 'depDate='+stringDate+"&depPort="+depPort+"&arrPort="+arrPort+'&triptype='+triptype+'&direction='+direction+'&route='+route+'&count='+count+"&class="+oddEven,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'html',
            //timeout: 30000,
            success: function(data)
            {
                if (data!='')
                {
                    $("#"+depPort+"_"+arrPort+"_holder").show();    
                    $("#"+depPort+"_"+arrPort+"_routes").append(data);
                    earlierCounter++;

                    if (earlierCounter == 1)
                    {
                        $("#you-can-options-up").show();
                        $("#you-can-options-bottom").show();
                    }

                    if ( oddEven == 'row1' ) { oddEven = 'row2'; } else { oddEven = 'row1'; }
                }               
            }
        });


    }


    if (  $("#"+depPort+"_"+arrPort+"_routes").html().length > 0  )
    {

    }
    else
    {
        $("#"+depPort+"_"+arrPort+"_error").show();
    }

    $("#"+depPort+"_"+arrPort).animate({height: '0px'}); 
    $("#"+depPort+"_"+arrPort).hide();  
    $(".loader").hide();

}
```

Comment: Do you have any error/exceptions in the console? First approach cannot work because loader is hided before any ajax request returns (they are asynchronous).

Comment: @hamczu no error occurs in console (firefox or chrome). I don;t understand your comment. I manually show the loader gif before i initialize any ajax call (and manually hide it at the end). If i set asynch to true, i don;t see any loader even in firefox. As if the show/hide never executes.

Comment: Can you show actual code of `for( 1 to 14 loop )`? If you change async to true, loader is hided before ajax request returns (as xdazz pointed).

Comment: @hamczu i have added original script in my question - but i don't see how this will help. It's nothing complicated - just some show/hide data in dynamic generated divs

Answer (score 0):

just place your loader where you show the result set i.e.

```
function myFunction(x,y,z)
{       
    $(".loader").html('loader.gif');

    for( 1 to 14 loop ) 
    {   
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'some.php',
            data: 'my data string here',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'html',
            //timeout: 30000,
            success: function(data)
            {
             $(".loader").html(data); 
            }
        }); 

    }

}
```

with this technique the result will overlap the loader

Comment: This solution is wrong - loader is hided after first ajax request returns.

Comment: @jassi9911 it is not possible to work. You replace loader gif with the html response data from the 1st ajax call. Then you replace the html data of 1st response with those frm 2nd response. This not what i want. Nor what i asked anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction(x, y, z) {
    $(".loader").show();
    var finished_count = 0;

    for (1 to 14 loop) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'some.php',
            data: 'my data string here',
            dataType: 'html',
            //timeout: 30000,
            success: function (data) {
                // do some stuff (show/hide divs, increase some counters, some maths, etc)
                //count finished ajax request.
                finished_count++;
                if (finished_count === 14) {
                    $(".loader").hide();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry xdazz, although a nice idea, it didn;t work for me. still i see no loader in chrome, ie

Comment: I think this is the correct answer for your question and you have problem in the other place of your code - maybe html/css issue. In addition try this with `async=false` - I have seen your depending on it by not execute ajax request in closure.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this helps

> I had the same issue and i really don't know how it's happening, but it can
>   be fixed using a small delay in code like follows.

### solution 1

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "/",
  beforeSend:function(){
    $(".loader").show(1);
    // please note i have added a delay of 1 millisecond , which runs almost same as code with no delay.
  },
  success:function(data){
    $(".loader").hide();
    //here i write success code
  }

});
```

### solution 2

```
   $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: "/",
      beforeSend:function(){

        setTimeout(function(){
           $(".loader-image").show();
        }, 1);
        // please note i have added a delay of 1 millisecond with js timeout function which runs almost same as code with no delay.
      },
      success:function(data){
        $(".loader-image").hide();
        //here i write success code
      }

    });
```